# How to add same JavaScript functionality for all the common part of web pages html file like navbar toggle, open submenu on mouseover

Tags: javascript, php, html, es6-modules, code-splitting

In my portfolio project there are some common html code snippet on about, projects, contact.html pages like navbar,footer and sidebar. The main app.js file contains toggling sidebar functionality, mouseover event on menus to open submenu, hint text on icon hover etc
How to add these functionality on every html pages.

We link app.js to every html pages, but there were showing various error like various element undefined since app.js has more code and element selection.

Comment: Extract the related code of toggling in one common js file and include that on all the required files.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid "hardcoding". Make [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) out of your developments.
Isolation and reuse is our everything :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).